# Square of absolute value of a function different than square of function

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

How come if f is measurable, we might have $|f|^2\neq f^2$? Can you provide an example? I think it is true if f is real.

Comment: If $f$ is real-valued, then there's no difference. If $f$ is complex-valued, then $f^2$ need not be positive (nor even real).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = \dfrac{i}{1+x^2}$. Simpler: consider $g(x) = i\chi_{[0,1]}(x).$

Comment: I will think on it later. I was not familiar with complex measurable functions.